# How to check whether sms in inbox is read or unread

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have fetched all message from a particular number from inbox by the following code .

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(
                Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst())
            return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            if (pre_address.equals(smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress))) {
                String str = "SMS From: "
                        + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) + "\n"
                        + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
                arrayAdapter.add(str);
            }
        } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Now I want to mark which sms are read and which are unread . How can I check which sms are read and which are unread ?

How can I check whether a sms is read or unread at the time of fetching from inbox ?

Comment: check this link it might help you..
https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/09/07/android-tutorial-mark-sms-as-read-unread/

Comment: I have checked it . But I require getting read and unread message from a particular number .

Comment: You merely need to check the `"read"` column. A value of `0` means _not read_, a value of `1` means _read_.

Comment: In that case , what will be the query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the colum index with `read` keyword:

```
int indexRead = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("read");
```

And then in your loop you can check it like this (`0 = not read` and `1 = read`):

```
boolean isRead = smsInboxCursor.getInt(indexRead) == 1;
```